# Embeded Google Map doesn't show "How to arrivle"

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I embedded a Google map (WordPress) and it works fine, but I made some changes to the page, deleted the previous map, and embedded it again, but now the button "How to arrive" does not show

This is what use to show:

[image]

An this is what is shown now:

[image]

I see that the whole box is different, it doesn't show the whole address now. What could I be doing wrong

I'm using embedgooglemap dot net

Rafael

Answer (score 0):

I already found out what the problem was.

The mimnimum width of the map must be 500 in order for the button to be shown